# how to use recognized certificate authority(like Digicert) to sign the cert to replace the kubernetes self-signed cert?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

In the kubernetes official document https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/ , it shows easyrsa, openssl or cfssl to generate certificates manually. According to the company policy, the self-signed certificate is insecure. Has anyone had similar experience to replace the cert? I also don't know if it is possible to do this thing. BTW, I'm talking about the kubernetes internal certificates instead of the cert with ingress-nginx to enable https.

Comment: I think it should be possible, for example with Vault, there is an [example](https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/using-vault) which use Vault as a CA. Could you take a look and let me know if that answer your question?

Comment: "self-signed certificate is insecure." is not true; it's the **action** of blindly accepting a self-signed certificate that is insecure, which kubernetes mitigates by requiring that the kubeconfig contain the public key of the CA to which it is communicating, or that the user explicitly choose `--insecure-skip-tls-verify`. As for your question, be forewarned that if you used a cert for which the apiserver does not have the key, it cannot do kubelet TLS renewal for you

Comment: @Jakub Thank you for your advice, I will try it later.

Comment: @mdaniel Thank you for your response, the security department runs "Nessus Tenable SC" to scan the server ports, the report shows in port 6443 "The X.509 certificate chain for this services is not signed by a recognized certificate authority." So I think replace the self-signed certs with digicert-generated certs can solve this problem. But I don't know if it is possible to do.

Comment: I think the main issue here would be the Nessus Tenable SC, you might need to configure it to recognize your ca cert. As a reference you might take a look at point 2 [here](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/1.5/how-to/backing-up). If you use kubeadm then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391705/11977760) might be helpful.